# How to efficiently create derived classes

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have a base class 'Person' and 3 derived classes, 'Student', 'Teacher' and 'Administrator'.

In a web application where a new person is created client side, on the server side, what is the most efficient way of creating the desired sub class without having to repeat all of the base class properties for every subclass.. In the example below I have had to repeat the Name, DOB and Address properties for each subclass.

```
void CreatePerson(someDto dto)
{
    Person person;

    if (dto.personType == 1)
    {
        person = new Student() { .. };
        person.Name = "";
        person.DOB = "";
        person.Address = "";
    }
    else if (dto.personType == 2)
    {
        person = new Teacher() { .. };
        person.Name = "";
        person.DOB = "";
        person.Address = "";
    }
    else if (dto.personType == 3)
    {
        person = new Administrator() { .. };
        person.Name = "";
        person.DOB = "";
        person.Address = "";
    }

    // Do something with person..
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move common stuff out of if/else

```
 if (dto.personType == 1)
    {
        person = new Student() { .. };
    }
    else if (dto.personType == 2)
    {
        person = new Teacher() { .. };

    }
    else if (dto.personType == 3)
    {
        person = new Administrator() { .. };
    }

    person.Name = ""; // I believe these 3 properties will come from dto
    person.DOB = "";
    person.Address = "";
```

Comment: Thanks @Tilak. Further, when setting the derived class properties inside the if blocks, it seems I have to do this within curly braces. I am not able to say 'person = new Student(); person.studentProperty = ...' is it a requirement to create derived class properties inside curly's?

Comment: Yes, [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: @Grant Actually, that should work. `x = new Type() { Property1 = value, Property2 = value }` is just a fancy way of writing `x = new Type(); x.Property1 = value; x.Property2 = value;`. Both should work in the same way.

Comment: @Tilak for some reason I cant write person.StudentProperty = "". I get a compiler error "'Person' does not contain a definition for 'StudentProperty'"

Comment: For that you need to cast Person into Student. You cannot assign any property that is not part of base class without cast